# USB Boot problem with Rufus

Tags: live-usb, rufus

I am trying to make bootable USB using Rufus.

I downloaded [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and selected the downloaded ISO but nothing happens.

As per the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
I should have been prompted to download syslinux SW,

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Rufus as in the guide?

Comment: no, the step by step shows 2,8,886, i'm using 2.9.934

Comment: Rufus author here. You will only be asked to download the Syslinux files if they don't already exist. If you used an ISO with the same version of Syslinux, Rufus will not ask you to download them again. In other words, you can safely ignore the part where Rufus asks you to download extra files, if it doesn't prompt you to.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, please do if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[From the comments](/questions/781276/usb-boot-problem-with-rufus?noredirect=1#comment1187495_781276):

> Rufus author here. You will only be asked to download the Syslinux files if they don't already exist. If you used an ISO with the same version of Syslinux, Rufus will not ask you to download them again. In other words, you can safely ignore the part where Rufus asks you to download extra files, if it doesn't prompt you to.

Summary: That behaviour is normal and not an error, just an oversight in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

**Note, this doesn't seem to work with UEFI and seems to only work on a legacy or BIOS system.**

Try using http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ instead.  Click on "Browse" to select the iso file you downloaded earlier.

If you need to re-download the iso, you can [click here to download the 64 bit version](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso).

Here is the sha256sum:

4bcec83ef856c50c6866f3b0f3942e011104b5ecc6d955d1e7061faff86070d4

This used to be the recommended method

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Use Universal USB Installer instead: [Link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
2. Format the USB drive first, then use Rufus
3. Change the device name to Rufus, volume name nothing, remove it, then click "Format"

Comment: it's all true ways but maybe he have other problem as:

Comment: sorry as: if the image iso not os or system able to be boot able it will not format , also if iso image broken , and this program rufus now is trojan at Avira , so uui peter , now i can give you more than one way and you try any you want, that's what i mean

Comment: @bassem - As per https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/Security#Executable_signature, it should be very easy to demonstrate if Rufus contains a troyan. Without proof (and because it happens so much that there's a [dedicated FAQ entry for it](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Antivirus_X_reports_that_Rufus_contains_malware)), this looks like yet another false positive from Avira.

Comment: True maybe it's false positive so i didn't told about that in my first comment, now you can tell Avira about that, regards